# Excel LINEST with INDIRECT to define Polynomial Order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the LINEST formula and I am using INDIRECT to define the X&Y Data however I can't work out how to use INDIRECT to define the Polynomial order. I have repeated Data sets where I need to change the order to see what fits best. I just want to change the a Cell value and update the Order

This works....
`=LINEST(INDIRECT(A1),INDIRECT(A2)^{1,2,3,4,5,6},TRUE,FALSE)`

where:
Cell A1 = `F4:F38`
Cell A2 = `E4:E38`

What I am trying to do is have the value of "6" in Cell A3, and that to make up the "1,2,3,4,5,6", in Cell A4, and changing it to 4 produces "1,2,3,4" in cell A4.

Cell A1 = `F4:F38`
Cell A2 = `E4:E38`
Cell A3 = `6`
Cell A4 = `1,2,3,4,5,6`

This doesn't work...
`=LINEST(INDIRECT(A1),INDIRECT(A2)^{INDIRECT(A4)},TRUE,FALSE)`

I have tried Cell A2 = `E4:E38^{1,2,3,4,5,6}` but this formula doesn't work either... `=LINEST(INDIRECT(A1),INDIRECT(A2),TRUE,FALSE)`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use SEQUENCE() if you have office 365:

```
=LINEST(INDIRECT(A1),INDIRECT(A2)^SEQUENCE(A4),TRUE,FALSE)
```

If not then ROW will work:

```
=LINEST(INDIRECT(A1),INDIRECT(A2)^ROW(INDIRECT("ZZ1:ZZ"&A4)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Older version using the 2nd formula may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Awesome thanks. the SEQUENCE(A4) didn't work however SEQUENCE(1,A3) does. So my new formula is `=LINEST(INDIRECT(A1),INDIRECT(A2)^SEQUENCE(1,A3),TRUE,FALSE)'.